# Unable to re-insert after unique key violation

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.1

I have the following scenario:

A business logic function that uses EF Core2 checks if a record already exists. If the record does not exists, it is inserted on the database.

I have multiple threads calling this business logic function. What happens is:

If the function is called simultaneous with the same parameters, both instances checks if the record exists - and it does not exists. So both instances inserts the same record.

When `context.SaveChanges()` is called on the first instance, all goes ok. But the second `SaveChanges()` throws an exception because the record already exists (there is an unique index on the database).

If i catch that exception and try to insert with new value for `UNIQUE_KEY`, still it's throwing an exception since previously added entity still in track.

How can I implement this to avoid the exception?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of simply adding a new entity inside your catch-block, you could modify the existing entity that caused the exception.

```
foreach (var entry in _dbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries<YourEntity>().Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Added)))
{
    entry.Entity.YourProperty = newvalue;
}
```

Just iterate through all your entities of given type and update your property that has a unique constraint.